# is synchronized Collection's toArray() method synchronized?

Tags: java, collections, synchronized

If I have a synchronized collection like this

`Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);`

javadoc for the `synchronizedCollection` mentiones that external iteration must be synchronized like this :

```
synchronized (c) {
 Iterator i = c.iterator();
 while (i.hasNext()) {
     process (i.next());
 }
}
```

Can I assume that `c.toArray()` is synchronized and therefore no changes to the collection will happen when the method executes?

Or do I need to synchronize it as well:

```
synchronized (c) {
  c.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Where does `CollectionUtils` come from? That is not a standard Java API class.

Comment: I assume he means `java.util.Collections`, not `CollectionUtils`.

Comment: It's Apache Commons Collections' utility class

Comment: nice catch, I actually meant the standard Collections class. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) for `synchronizedCollection`:

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) collection backed by the specified collection.

Thus, `c.toArray()` does not require any additional synchronization. `SynchronizedCollection`'s `toArray()` method will do the locking for you. In essence, that's the whole point of `synchronizedCollection()`.

If you want to confirm that this reading of the contract agrees with the actual implementation, see [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection.toArray%28%29).

Comment: Thanks that pretty much says it all. And GrepCode is fantastic!

Comment: Absolutely incorrect.  You CANNOT and SHOULD NOT rely on the implementation of the code.  You MUST rely on the contract supplied, and since there seems to not be a contract supplied you CANNOT assume it is synchronized.

Comment: @Woot4Moo The `synchronized*` methods' javadocs are pretty general -- does that mean we should never use them? All it really says is that it's thread-safe, but I think it's safe to assume that this means *all* its methods are thread-safe. The warning/example about iterators also highly implies that the thread safety comes from synchronizing on the returned object.

Comment: @yshavit It means you need to follow the contract, irrespective of the "general" contract, the specific one dictates functionality.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I know what you meant -- my question was rhetorical. In this case, there is no precise contract except that the collection is "thread-safe" and that you should synchronize on it before iterating over it. So, if you want a precise contract where every method's thread safety is explicitly stated, you just can't use those collections at all. I would consider this a pretty extreme position of design-by-contract.

Comment: @yshavit I would consider it within the normal bounds of design by contract.  However, I am going to avoid starting a holy war of DbC concepts.  So lets just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Apache's commons collection utility the answer is yes. `CollectionUtils.synchronizedCollection(...)` returns an instance of `SynchronizedCollection` who's `toArray()` method is:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return collection.toArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant the standard `java.util.Collections` class. But I can see that the asnwer is the same for both.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it, the method performs the synchronization for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java.util.Collections which is part of the standard Java Collection API, then all methods on the returned SynchronizedCollection is synchronized including toArray(). See code blocks below, taken from Java source code in java.util.Collections.SynchronizedCollection.

```
public Object[] toArray() {
   synchronized(mutex) {return c.toArray();}
}

public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
   synchronized(mutex) {return c.toArray(a);}
}
```

Comment: No.  You must rely on the contract not the implementation.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I agree with you that one should not rely on the implementation, only on the contract. The code snippets from the java source code was to give a clearer idea of what is really going on. The JavaDoc clearly states _Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) collection backed by the specified collection_ which is interpreted as all methods on the returned collection are synchronized. I don't think there is any ambiguity in the docs on that.

Comment: if you read the full doc it clearly states iteration must be synchronized.  If you can convert between data structures without iteration please show me.

Comment: The doc states _It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it_ i.e. the synchronization must be done on the returned SynchronizedCollection object itself. If this is not done, then methods that modify the collection can interleave with your iteration of the collection even though the modifying methods are themselves synchronized. This does not in anyway mean the toArray() method of the `SynchronizedCollection` needs to be synchronized **again**. toArray() does not need any external synchronization and this is by contract. Hope this helps!

Comment: Once again, a toArray is an implicit iteration. "Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior. " From the doc that you are referring to. The issue you are running into in understanding is that you see the source code. Let me make this simple. What does the following function do? `public Object doStuff() {...}` based on its contract.

Comment: Again, the comment in the docs is with regard to iterating over the returned SynchronizedCollection and it is very clear about this. You could even argue that it has exposed an implementation detail. Now with regarding to toArray(), I don't think there is any ambiguity in the docs, the docs says you are getting a SynchronizedCollection, so all methods on it are synchronized. You should not be making assumptions about implicit iterations or otherwise. I suggest that you read the docs once again, without taking it out of context.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to a be a large misconception going on here that you can rely on the actual source code implementation.  This is false, you must rely on the contract of the method.  Since the contract does not exist you cannot assume it will do something, at any point in time the underlying implementation can change.  For instance look at the following function:

```
/**  
*  Returns an empty Collection of Books.
*  
*  
* /  
public Collection returnEmptyBooks()  
{  
    return new HashSet<Book>();
}
```

This implies I can return anything that implements the Collection interface.  Signature plus documentation.  You could not assume that it is synchronized or anything else of that nature.  You could also deduce that you will not ever get null back from this method, unless the contract has been violated.

In case no one reads the comments.  Any conversion from one data structure to another implies iteration.  You cannot move from List to Set without iterating over all of the elements.  The same would apply with a conversion to an Array.  You must fill the Array by iterating over your initial data structure, therefore it needs to be synchronized.

Comment: I don't think I get your point. If by contract you mean strictly a method's signature, then in your example above it's not true that returning null from the `returnEmptyBooks()` is violating the contract. In fact any method returning any java.lang.Object can return null and it may only be a **convention** to return empty Collection and not null. This convention is implementation specific and by your reasoning you shouldn't trust it either.

Comment: @artur Contract means signature + documentation. If you look at the documentation provided it explicitly states it will return an empty Collection of Books. My reasoning still stands as a piece of code that would invoke this would be guaranteed to receive an empty Collection and not null. If null was returned it would be a contract violation. There are far more things that go into DbC than just function declarations.

Comment: I get ya. But coming back to my original question, the javadoc explicitly says _returns a synchronized (thread-safe) collection_. Based on this you're still not happy that you can assume that the toArray() of retruned Collection is synchronized and threadsafe?

Comment: @artur Correct that is what the javadoc states and I am happy with that.  What it also states is that if iteration is performed you must use a synch block.  Fundamentally any conversion from one data structure to another involves an iteration, therefore you need to synch the block.  So to answer your question, no I do not believe that is a strong enough argument to say no synch block.

Comment: Ok, I take your point. I guess we could argue till the end of the world. My question arised from exactly the fact that I assumed that toArray() would involve some iteration, but note that this is **implementation detail**. You're assuming that iteration is required, but the contract doesn't say it so as a hardcore DbC proponent you shouldn't jump to conclusions. I can imagine this conversion to be done by some wild bytecode manipulation, but that's not the point. The contract promises synchronized collection and peaking at the implementation gives you exactly that.